# how to make query with substr in eloquent (laravel 4)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, substr, eloquent

I have this query:

```
select substr(id,1,4) as id
from meteo.a2012
group by substr(id,1,4)
```

I just want to take first 4 numbers to my id row, but I'm trying to do in eloquent, how I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [raw expressions](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) so you can use special functions like that.

```
Model::select(DB::raw('substr(id, 1, 4) as id'))->groupBy(DB::raw('substr(id, 1, 4)'))->get();
```

Where `Model` is your Eloquent model you want to run the query on.

Comment: Thanks, did not know the raw method

Answer (score 1):

G'day

I was able to do it like this in Laravel

```
 $data = DataModel::selectRaw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(EMAIL_COLUMN, '@', 1) as 'alias'")->get();
```

As a result, I get the alias name (address) from the mail address@domain.net

Comment: Okay this helped me Laravel 9, thx alot bro :D

Answer (score -1):

```
$ids = Model::get(['id']);
foreach ($ids as $str)
{
    $str->id =substr($str->id,1,4);
}
return $ids;
```