# Limit Eloquent database results

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying create a query to output all my users but limit thier last name to one character for privacy reasons. I can seem to find a clean way to do this through Laravals Eloquent model.

```
public function getAll(){
    $users = User::get(array('id', 'fname', 'lname'));
    return $users
}
```

Desired response:
{
id: 1,
fname: "Luca",
lname: "D"
}

Comment: I don't know laravel and so I can't help you with that, but can't you just limit their last name on output? I mean the query itself doesn't have to actually pull only the one character if you only display one character. Also, a quick google found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626702/how-to-make-query-with-substr-in-eloquent-laravel-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Laravels raw expresions](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) with [LEFT SQL function.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

```
 $users = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('id, fname, LEFT(lname,1) as last_name'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
public function index()
{
    $mymodel = MyModel::all();

    return View::make('MyModel.index')->with('MyModel', $mymodel);
}
```

And then have a view which just foreach between them, if this is what you're trying todo

```
@foreach($mymodel as $key => $model)
{{ $model->username }}
@endforeach
```

isn't this it what you're trying todo render all users on a page?